# Why do I get signal SIGABRT when I select a created button?

Tags: ios, button, swift2, sigabrt

I'm creating a `button` in swift 2 and when I select it, I get signal SIGABRT and the app crashes. Heres the code:

```
    let button = UIButton()//(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton!
    button.setTitle("button", forState: .Normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonPressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)
    self.view.addSubview(button)
    func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton!) {
        print("ButtonIsSelected")
    }
```

It brings me to AppDelegate.swift and in the middle of the `NSLog` it says: unrecognized selector sent to instance...
Please help. Anton

Comment: buttonPressed should be defined at the class method level instead of inside your setup method

Comment: Thanks. It works great now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton!) {
    print("ButtonIsSelected")
}
```

This method must be in your class body not in function body . As I guess you have done.