# SIGABRT error in swift 2

Tags: ios, swift2, sigabrt

I recently updated my app to Swift 2, and had one error, which I solved thanks to you guys.
And now, I have a second error, which is at runtime, when I press the one button to play a sound. It is a signal SIGABRT error.

Here is the error message I get in the debug console:

```
2016-01-25 09:16:09.019 WarningShot1.0.0[291:19030] -[WarningShot1_0_0.ViewController playMySound:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x135547d30
2016-01-25 09:16:09.021 WarningShot1.0.0[291:19030] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[WarningShot1_0_0.ViewController playMySound:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x135547d30'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x182835900 0x181ea3f80 0x18283c61c 0x1828395b8 0x18273d68c 0x18755fe50 0x18755fdcc 0x187547a88 0x18755f6e4 0x18755f314 0x187557e30 0x1875284cc 0x187526794 0x1827ecefc 0x1827ec990 0x1827ea690 0x182719680 0x183c28088 0x187590d90 0x10005e2e0 0x1822ba8b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Also, this is the part of the code where it throws this error, in the second line, where the class is declared:

```
 import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
-> class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
```

What is happening here? What am I missing / misnaming? What do I need to change in my code to get ot running again. This app is ridiculously simple, and worked for months under the last version of Swift. Why is it now giving me errors?

Thank you for your help.

Here is the code for my ViewController.swift file:

```
import UIKit
```

import AVFoundation
import CoreMotion

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
var myPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

var mySound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("RemSound_01", ofType: "wav")!)

func initYourSound() {
    do {
        try myPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: mySound, fileTypeHint: nil)
    myPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    // myPlayer.volume = 1.0 // < for setting initial volume, still not perfected.
    } catch {
        // handle error
    }

var motionManager = CMMotionManager()

var currentMaxAccelY : Double = 0.0

func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initYourSound()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //set motion manager properties
    motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.17

    //start recording data
    //        motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue(), withHandler: {
    //            (accelerometerData: CMAccelerometerData!,error:NSError!) -> Void in
    //            self.outputAccelerationData(accelerometerData.acceleration)
    //            if(error != nil) {
    //                print("\(error)")
    //            }
    //        })
    motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()!, withHandler: {
        (accelerometerData,error) in outputAccelerationData(accelerometerData!.acceleration)
        if(error != nil) {
            print("\(error)", terminator: "")
        }
    })
}

//func outputAccelerationData(acceleration : CMAcceleration){
    //  accY?.text = "\(acceleration.y).2fg"
    //if fabs(acceleration.y) > fabs(currentMaxAccelY)
    //{
    //  currentMaxAccelY = acceleration.y
    //}
    //        maxAccY?.text = "\(currentMaxAccelY) .2f"
    //}

func outputAccelerationData(acceleration : CMAcceleration){
    if fabs(acceleration.y) >= 1.25 {
        myPlayer.play()
    }
}

func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func playMySound(sender: AnyObject) {
    myPlayer.play()
}

// self.resetMaxValues()
// @IBOutlet var accY: UILabel!
// @IBOutlet var maxAccY: UILabel!

// @IBAction func resetMaxValues() {
//   currentMaxAccelY = 0
// }
```

}
}

Comment: show the code related playMySound

Comment: how is the button created ?

Comment: The error says: In the class `ViewController` the method `playMySound:` is missing.

Comment: Just added the code of my ViewController.swift file.

Comment: Another comment on my app: I get one error message saying "All interface orientations must be supported unless the app requires full screen"
My app does require Portrait orientation, and is full screen. This is also a new error message, so what do I do to get rid of it? I just feel like scrapping the entire code and starting from scratch. But then I'll probably end up with more errors.

Comment: There is a closing brace missing at the end of `initYourSound()`

Comment: This is THE most common runtime error, and is such a common question on Stack Overflow that I can't even be bothered to pick out a duplicate. Please, in future, search before asking.

Answer (score 0):

"unrecognized selector sent to instance" means that there is a mismatch between the action-name in "addTarget()" and the name of the function you want to call. Probably something with the parameters of the function.. It's hard to say without seeing any code.

```
action: Selector("playMySound:")
```

would expect to find a function:

```
func playMySound(sender: AnyObject?) {};
```

Comment: Just added the code of my ViewController.swift file.

Comment: The function is there, I added the entire Viewcontroller.swift code to my original question. Thanks

Comment: Where are you calling the function?? 
Are you using Storyboard?

Comment: I was calling it via @IBaction, but apparently the conversion to Swift 2 erased this command before the function, and does NOT allow it anymore. This is truly a crappy "update" no matter what people say, it totally broke a working app, LOL: 

IBAction func playMySound(sender: AnyObject) {
        myPlayer.play()

Comment: I just found this, where I have to put my button HAS to be implemented inside the class. I think at this point I am just going to start from scratch, it will take less time, and should (lol right) build this app with the correct swift 2 ins outs and new "improvements". I looked at the changes, and the conversion changed 9 or more things, which means at least 9 or more bugs I have to "fix". This is not progress.

[link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477470/why-do-i-get-signal-sigabrt-when-i-select-a-created-button?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

To easier track what's happening, you might add a symbolic breakpoint for all exceptions. You do that in Xcode on the "exceptions" tab (left part of the window) and when an exception is thrown, Xcode stops like usual and you might look up the stack trace. If the call is synchronous, you should easily find and see your mistake.

EDIT: Oh well, you seem to have done the user interface using a XIB file. The mistake could be, you wired the button's action in the XIB file to the view controller. If you later change the method's signature (parameter, name, etc.), UIKit can't find the method. Open the XIB and fix your error. ;-)

Comment: I only have one XIB file, the launch screen. It does not interact with anything. The user interface is only one ViewController. And it only has two interactions in it: a button, which is causing an error when pressed of SIGABRT, and a motion sensor, which is not even working since the button crashes the app.